# Expression in Property Transfer for XML response in SOAPUI

Tags: automated-testing, soapui

I am trying to get a sessionID value from an XML response after a http request. However the response is not a clear XML, so I can't write a propertly expression to get this value.

Any idea to do that?

Response of the HTTP Request

[image: Response of HTTP Request]

[image: Property Transfer]

Answer (score 1):

Use Groovy:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ) 
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SOAP CALL ID#response" )  

// Extract ProposalId field from the XML
def dataString = responseHolder.getNodeValue["//<CMFResponse><ReturnCode>"]
// Use split to extract the required data
def temp1, temp2, sessionId
temp1 = dataString.split("SessionID=")
temp2 = temp1.split("]]>")
sessionID = temp2[0]
```

Mark Smith